# Calculating Solar Radiation falling on vertical surfaces using DEMs and ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, dem, spatial-analyst

I am using ArcGIS10 Area Solar Radiation tool to calculate irradiation on horizontal surfaces (building roofs) but need to do the same for vertical surfaces (building facades).

Any ideas on how to do this using ArcGIS and DEMs?

I am open to broader suggestions on what tools to use, just needs to run for large portions of a city (neighbourhood scale) at once, instead of building level.

Comment: Could you say a little more about what you mean by running this calculation at a "neighborhood scale" rather than at the "building level"?  Also, what data do you have concerning the vertical surfaces?  (Most DEMs have no building height information.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! By neighbourhood scale I mean that I analyse many buildings at once (with a population of around 1500 people), instead of just one building. I said this because that makes the analysis area larger and hence more computing intense. My DEMs are based on buildings and their elevation is based on the building height, rather than terrain.

Comment: As an occasional user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.